# Python function not picking updated list values

Tags: python

I have two functions, **updates_list** updates values to the list **altered_source_tables** while the other picks the values in that list. The issue is, even though the first function updates the list, the second function **use_list** still has the list as empty.

```
altered_source_tables = []  
table_name = 'table_1'    
def updates_list(table_name, **kwargs):
    # CODE
    for e in job.errors: 
        fullstring = e['message']
        substring = "No such field"
        if search(substring, fullstring):
            altered_source_tables.append(table_name) 
            print("altered_source_tables list ", altered_source_tables) # output from fn call: altered_source_tables = ['table_1']
        else:
            print('ERROR: {}'.format(e['message']))            
            
        

def use_list(**kwargs): 
    print("altered_source_tables list ", altered_source_tables) # output from fn call: altered_source_tables = []
    if len(altered_source_tables) > 0:
        # Loop through  all altered tables
        for table_name in altered_source_tables:
            # CODE
```

What I'm I missing?

Comment: Do you actually call the functions?

Comment: @Sidney yes, the functions are being called. The output of the second function indicated the list is still empty.

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: What arguments do you pass in the functions?

Comment: also you are calling a lot of stuff from outside the function. This is a but dangerous and looks like you are using threads. As mentioned already reduce your function to only the problematic part

Comment: If `print(job.result())` and `print(job.output_rows)` can be executed inside the `try:` the `altered_source_tables.append(table_name)` will never run because it is inside the `except:`.

Comment: @Sefan ``altered_source_tables.append(table_name)`` is running and the output is as indicated on the above code

Comment: @ShadowWalker it is not possible to reproducible the error with this code.